# matlab which filtfilt function handles filter objects

Tags: matlab, filtering

According to matlab's `filtfilt` documentation, it can receive several arrays (depending in which representation; a-b, sos-k-g; you are using) and a filter object.

However if I type `edit filtfilt`, that code only handles the array cases...

So,anyone know where can I find how `filtfilt` handles filter objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtfilt.html#d117e61389) the object must be of type `digitalFilter`. An overloaded version of the `filtfilt` function for such an object can be edited by typing

```
edit digitalFilter/filtfilt
```

To list all overloaded methods of a function, type

```
which -all filtfilt
```

This shows a list of all the M-files that implement a function or method with that name.